# Randomly name computer before joining domain

Tags: powershell

We are going to create an image for 2000 computer and all of them will be joined to a domain trought a vpn connection.

I need to add the vpn connection, connect to it, generate a random name for the computer and then join it to a domain trought vpn.

The part where im stuck is how to generate a random name for the computer for the `-NewName` option. I searched for a while now but my time is short for this task and I cant afford to waste any more time with research.

Comment: "can't afford to waste any more time with research" - I would recommend rephrasing. You may not have intended, but some may interpret this as saying your time is more valuable than anyone else's.

Comment: I coded a `MakeUp-String` cmdlet a while ago where you can easily create a string and define its complexity and length, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256154/powershell-password-generator-how-to-always-include-number-in-string

Answer (score 2):

If you just want random letters:

```
-join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 10 | foreach {[char]$_})
```

Gives an output like:

> roQZctqCEa

Change the `-Count` param to reflect how many letters you want.

We take a random selection of numbers in the ranges (65..90) + (97..122) then converts these to letters by using the [char] Type. The number ranges corrospond the upper and lower case letters. The returned array of letters is turned into a string by `-join`

If you only want Capital Letters:

```
-join ((65..90) | Get-Random -Count 10 | foreach {[char]$_})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Guid` for that and crop everything after 13 characters:

```
([guid]::NewGuid()).Guid -replace '(.{13}).*', '$1'
```

One example output:

```
30284801-59e6
```

Comment: computer name shouldn't be longer than 15 characters

Comment: @4c74356b41 You are right, didnt knew about that limitations - updated my answer.

Comment: Entire GUIDs are random, but substrings of GUIDs are not guaranteed to be random. Also, this would not prevent name collisions; it would merely make them unlikely.