# Random Password function

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a PowerShell function that generates a random password. I have found many however not a single one does what I want.

I want function that will generate a password X inputted length while using Y special characters, either securely or plain text.

Any recommendations ?

Comment: See also: [PowerShell - Password Generator - How to always include number in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275209/1701026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function New-Password {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        $Passwordlength = 10,

        $Specialcharacters = 2
    )

    begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
    }

    process {
        Write-Verbose "Creating new password $passwordlength characters long with $specialcharacters special characters"
        [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword($passwordlength,$specialcharacters)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Doug! This works like I want.  I think I can tweak it to give it a secure string option.

Answer (score 0):

For generating the passwords, you can use the `secret` module in python.
It provides access to the most secure source of randomness that your operating system provides.

For generating an eight-character alphanumeric password:

```
import string
import secrets
password_len = 8
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(password_len))
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) of the secret module.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I don't think System.Web.Security.Membership works in PS7.

Answer (score 0):

```
function New-Password {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Generate a random password.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Generate a random password.
    .NOTES
        Change log:
            27/11/2017 - faustonascimento - Swapped Get-Random for System.Random.
                                            Swapped Sort-Object for Fisher-Yates shuffle.
            17/03/2017 - Chris Dent - Created.
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([String])]
    param (
        # The length of the password which should be created.
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]        
        [ValidateRange(8, 255)]
        [Int32]$Length = 12,

        # The character sets the password may contain. A password will contain at least one of each of the characters.
        [String[]]$CharacterSet = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                                   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                   '123456789',
                                   '!$%&^-@'),

        # The number of characters to select from each character set.
        [Int32[]]$CharacterSetCount = (@(1) * $CharacterSet.Count)
    )

    begin {
        $bytes = [Byte[]]::new(4)
        $rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()
        $rng.GetBytes($bytes)

        $seed = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($bytes, 0)
        $rnd = [Random]::new($seed)

        if ($CharacterSet.Count -ne $CharacterSetCount.Count) {
            throw "The number of items in -CharacterSet needs to match the number of items in -CharacterSetCount"
        }

        $allCharacterSets = [String]::Concat($CharacterSet)
    }

    process {
        try {
            $requiredCharLength = 0
            foreach ($i in $CharacterSetCount) {
                $requiredCharLength += $i
            }

            if ($requiredCharLength -gt $Length) {
                throw "The sum of characters specified by CharacterSetCount is higher than the desired password length"
            }

            $password = [Char[]]::new($Length)
            $index = 0
        
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $CharacterSet.Count; $i++) {
                for ($j = 0; $j -lt $CharacterSetCount[$i]; $j++) {
                    $password[$index++] = $CharacterSet[$i][$rnd.Next($CharacterSet[$i].Length)]
                }
            }

            for ($i = $index; $i -lt $Length; $i++) {
                $password[$index++] = $allCharacterSets[$rnd.Next($allCharacterSets.Length)]
            }

            # Fisher-Yates shuffle
            for ($i = $Length; $i -gt 0; $i--) {
                $n = $i - 1
                $m = $rnd.Next($i)
                $j = $password[$m]
                $password[$m] = $password[$n]
                $password[$n] = $j
            }

            [String]::new($password)
        } catch {
            Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
        }
    }
}
```

is something I found.
https://gist.github.com/indented-automation/2093bd088d59b362ec2a5b81a14ba84e