# Install as local admin user

Tags: powershell, installation, intune

I have a task of installing applications through Intune, 98% of all the installations are fine. but I have an issue with some of them.

The issue is when an application can't be installed or just run by the system account.

I've tried to create a local admin account, and then let the script start the other script as that account, but here the windows security kicks in - the system account is not allowed to run Start-Process

I use PSExec64.exe to start the powershell.exe

here is the code to do the install

```
$InstallUser = "IntuneInstaller"
$password = -join ((33..126) | Get-Random -Count 32 | ForEach-Object {[char]$_})

$passwordSecure =  ConvertTo-SecureString  -AsPlainText $password -Force

$null = New-LocalUser "$InstallUser" -Password $passwordSecure -FullName "$InstallUser" -Description "Automated Install Account" -AccountNeverExpires -PasswordNeverExpires
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "$InstallUser" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($InstallUser,$passwordSecure)

Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Credential ($Credentials) -WorkingDirectory "c:\sysman" -ArgumentList "c:\SysMan\WriteMyNameInTheSand.ps1 -MyName $env:USERNAME -MyLocation c:\sysman -MyMessage $password" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden

Remove-LocalUser -Name "$InstallUser"
```

It woks fine if I run it as adminstrator - but if I run it as Systemaccount I get the error:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.
At C:\SysMan\RunInstallAsAdminUser.ps1:20 char:1
+ Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential ($Credentials) -WorkingDirec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Anyone with a good sugestion?

Comment: Note that `Start-Process -Credential` never creates an _elevated_ session, so if your installer requires that, it may explain the error.

Answer (score 1):

The troubleshooting question here is:

- When you rerun it in the same environment, does it always fail?

The point is that you take for the password all the characters between `[char]33` and `[char]126` which might include characters that might affect or even break the command line for the [`PowerShell.exe` command-line interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) as e.g. a single quote (`'`):

```
$Message = "te'st"
Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-Command Write-Host $Message" -Wait
```

> The string is missing the terminator: '.
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

In other words, you might want to use a more sophisticated password generator as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275209)

Creating a temporary account with a random password might be a smart thing to do here but passing a plaintext password to the `C:\SysMan\RunInstallAsAdminUser.ps1` script isn't secure (someone might simply spoof that script and create a few other admin accounts).

As for `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force` statement, a [SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) and if you do:

> ⚠️ [**Important**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0#securestring-operations)
>
> A **SecureString** object should never be constructed from a **String**, because the sensitive data is already subject to the memory persistence consequences of the immutable **String** class. The best way to construct a **SecureString** object is from a character-at-a-time unmanaged source, such as the **Console.ReadKey** method.

Meaning instead of this:

```
$password = -join ((65..90) | Get-Random -Count 32 | ForEach-Object {[char]$_})
$passwordSecure =  ConvertTo-SecureString  -AsPlainText $password -Force
```

It is safer to do this:

```
$passwordSecure = [SecureString]::New()  
(65..90) | Get-Random -Count 32 | ForEach-Object { $passwordSecure.AppendChar([Char]$_) }
```

Comment: Good points, but I still wonder if the lack of elevation is the primary problem here.

Comment: The problem was not the password string - but the fact that the system account is not allowed to do Start-Process using -Credential flag. 
Makes sense, that a system account should not be able to start a process as a user.
Yes, the system starts a process as a local/domain user in scheduled task - but here is is flaged as started as sheduled task.